# Error in ajax call on onsubmit event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling a javascript function on onSubmit event of a textfield
this way:

```
  <form action="#" onsubmit="getTestResults()">
        <input class="button2" type="text" name="barcode" >
   </form>
```

and javascript function is:

```
function getTestResults(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url : "uploadTestResult.htm",
            success : function(response) {
                alert(response);
                $("#testResultCount0").html(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

But I am getting error: HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported
I am using type as post.
I don't want to submit whole form.
Is it right way or is their any alternate way?
plz suggest

Comment: Try using POST instead of Post

Comment: You are not sending POST data

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `return false;` at the end of the `getTestResults` function.

Comment: Guys...
I tried all the above given techniques but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Do this to submit the form using AJAX and send data using POST

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="#" onsubmit="getTestResults()">
     <input class="button2" type="text" name="barcode" >
</form>

function getTestResults(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "uploadTestResult.htm",
        data: $("#uploadForm").serialize(),
        success : function(response) {
            alert(response);
            $("#testResultCount0").html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```